# MPMediapickercontroller tab bar overlap with custom tab bar in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I can hide or unhide tab bar in navigation controller. But issue when I use `presentModelViewController` of `MPMediapickercontroller`, and even when hiding custom tab bar, it overlaps the tab bar of `MPMediapickercontroller`.

Please take a look at this image.

[image]
This is a default 'MPMediapickercontroller' presented.

I have been surfing to find this fix but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `MPMediapickercontroller` its always present modally. so one solution for that is you have to use image which is same as tabbar of `MPMediapickercontroller`.

Here is that image. use without any border just white image thats it.[image: tab bar appearance]

Now, below is my code.

In Viewwillappear method you have to set that image in tabbar appearance.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
       [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabDefault"]];
       [super viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

Then whatever you want `presentModelViewController` of `MPMediapickercontroller`

in last you done all things then you have to use `dealloc` method to set `Tabbar` same as you required permanent.

```
-(void)dealloc
 {
   [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab2"]];
 }
```

I solved my problem from this. hope you done it.